# VS2017 15.5 installs .NET core 2.1.2?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I've installed the 15.5 update for VS2017 on two separate machines. I now see on both that I have something claiming to be ​Microsoft .NET Core SDK - 2.1.2 (x64). I've found no trace of this on Google. Is this a mistake? A prerelease?

[image]

Comment: Issues already reported: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1799, https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1131.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected.

The 2.1.2 release of the .NET Core SDK (not runtime!) contains the same MSBuild version, build extensions and SDKs (the bits referenced `<Project Sdk="(this SDK string)">`) as VS 2017 15.5.

At the time of writing, the official download sites have not been updated to include this release.

The source code for this release can be found in the [`release/2.1` branch of the dotnet/cli GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/tree/release/2.1).